# What is basic knowledge wanted from a bachelor mechanical engineering student before joining?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, thermodynamics, automotive-engineering

At the moment, I just finished my senior school year and in a few months, I will be studying mechanical engineering as bachelor degree. However, I don’t like to waste my time and want to use this time wisely in preparing myself well before entering mechanical engineering.

What type of mathematics should I further practice apart from calculus? Should I go further in the studying of calculus, more specifically, should I go more of just the basics that are learnt in schools?

Should I learn all chapter in the book from physics including nuclear physics etc?

What about chemistry?

Please let me know what you think and don’t hesitate to give your opinion.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This question is too open to opinions. The general point of a bachelor's degree is to teach you what you need to know. If you know where you will be studying, you should know what classes they require you to take. That is your guide.

Comment: Just make sure you have all of high school math down solid. Don't worry about the physics too much, chances are they will re-teach it to you better. In case you did enough physics in high school to place out, consider taking the honors version of the physics classes your first year (or the 'hard science' version instead of the 'engineering version'). If you don't like it you can always bail. Same for CS. Can be a challenge, but big reward. In general, anything you're considering placing out of, make sure you really know.

Answer (score 1):

As much math as you can get.  Knowing basic chemistry and physics will help.  ME physics is strictly newtonian stuff.  They'll teach you everything else.  Tech tip - get a calculator that changes from polar to cartesian coordinates & statics will be a breeze.